# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'refresh': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

**Script Error:**
`SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'refresh': object is null or undefined`
`eval code (17), line 387 character 5`

**The code it is referring to is this:**
386 `var win = $('#kendoWindow1').data('kendoWindow');`
387 `win.refresh('http://www.google.com/');`

**Steps to recreate error:**
1. Load page
2. Click on link to open Kendo Window
3. Close Kendo Window
4. Refresh the entire page
5. Click on link to open Kendo Window
6. Error appears in the Script debugging tool (IE 8 & IE 9)

**Question:**
How can I resolve this error? For some reason `win` is `undefined` when refreshing the page which seems to be the cause, but why would it be undefined on refresh when it was fine before refresh?

Comment: was a solution ever found?

Answer (score 1):

I'm willing to bet that `kendoWindow1` is an *id* and not an *element*.

Your selector should be:

```
var win = $('#kendoWindow1').data('kendoWindow');
```

Comment: My fault, it actually is var win = $('#kendoWindow1').data('kendoWindow'); The problem is on refreshing the page win is undefined. It works perfectly fine when the page first loads, but reloading the page makes it undefined.